# Is possible to transfer assets to different SFMC accounts without any relation between them?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, content-builder, package-manager

I know that we can use Package manager to tranfer Journeys, Automations, Activities, templates, etc... between different BUs, but we can use it also to transfer this assets to a different SFMC account without any relation? Is there is any way to do this?

Comment: Package Manager works across instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package manager can be used across different MC orgs, it's not limited to BU-only transfers.
Simply upload the json/zip downloaded in the instance you'd like.